# SQL Server properties Is Clustered matters in ordering

Tags: sql-server-2005

i have a doubt. in Production Server , Sql Server properties -> opened properties of server using object browser -> there is one property 'Is Clustered' which is set as true.

but in my local region it is set as false. If i write any query using temp tables with order by in both the server, will it show me the same result or different.

this question is in conjunction with my previous question which is related to ordering of result using dynamic sql, temp tables.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IsClustered` in Server properties refers to 'Failover Clustering'. It has nothing to do with clustered indexes or the ordering of data.

The Collation order of your local server might be different to that of production...

Comment: thanks for response. but both the collation are same only. Is there can any other parameter which can make this difference

Comment: have you checked collation of both tempDB's?